# Persisting 3rd party entities in browser storage with JPA

Tags: java, gwt, jpa, local-storage, errai

I have two projects (app.ui & models). models is a dependency in app.ui. There we have all the  entity classes. app.ui is an errai project that uses JPA to save objects in the browser's storage.

So, I'm following the documentation in terms of annotations and stuff. If I create a class in app.ui and try to save it locally, it works. But if I have the same class with the exact same annotations in models.jar

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.magick.models.shared.Strategy is not a known entity type
  org.jboss.errai.jpa.client.local.ErraiMetamodel.entity(ErraiMetamodel.java:92)
  org.jboss.errai.jpa.client.local.ErraiMetamodel.entity(ErraiMetamodel.java:108)
  org.jboss.errai.jpa.client.local.ErraiMetamodel.entity(ErraiMetamodel.java:113)
  org.jboss.errai.jpa.client.local.ErraiEntityManager.changeEntityState(ErraiEntityManager.java:180)
  org.jboss.errai.jpa.client.local.ErraiEntityManager.persist(ErraiEntityManager.java:469)
  app.client.local.strategy.StrategyProducer.saveStrategyLocally(StrategyProducer.java:83)
  app.client.local.strategy.StrategyProducer.saveStrategiesInBrowser(StrategyProducer.java:78)
  app.client.local.strategy.StrategyProducer.access$3(StrategyProducer.java:76)
  app.client.local.strategy.StrategyProducer$1$1.callback(StrategyProducer.java:68)
  app.client.local.strategy.StrategyProducer$1$1.callback(StrategyProducer.java:1)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will get back on this. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this work, the model that needs to be persisted on browser's local storage it should be annotated with `@Entity` and should reside in the client-side package as errai ignores persistence.xml for `errai-jpa-client` and scans it in the client side package.

That is, in the package that GWT compiles.

Also try to use the browser plugin to check for the contents of local storage.

Hope this helps.